# Flutter. How to track the opening of a notification from APNS

Tags: flutter, notifications, apple-push-notifications

How can I track the opening of a notification on ios if it is sent via APNS without binding to firebase messaging?

How do I understand that the user has opened the application by clicking on this notification?

I tried tracking using FirebaseMessaging.onMessage, but it doesn't work